# AngularJS watch is not hitting in controller even after making the change in Service variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is my code.

```
sampleApp.factory('ProductService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q){
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'ProductData.txt',
        //url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/superCategory.pl',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }//,
        //data: { action: 'GET' }
    };  
    var ProductService =  {};
    ProductService.Products = [];
    return {
        GetProducts: function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http(req).then(function(response) {
                ProductService.Products = response.data;
                defer.resolve(ProductService.Products);
            }, function(error) {
                defer.reject("Some error");
            });
            return defer.promise;
        },

        UpdateInfo: function (ProductID, VariantID) {

            for (i in ProductService.Products) {
                if (ProductService.Products[i].ProductID == ProductID) {
                    for (j in ProductService.Products[i].Variants)  {
                        if (ProductService.Products[i].Variants[j].VariantID == VariantID) {
                            ProductService.Products[i].Variants[j].InCart = 1;    /* Updating Info Here, But its not reflecting */ 
                            alert ('information updated');      // reaching here
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}]);


sampleApp.controller('ProductsController', function ($scope, $routeParams, ProductService, ShoppingCartService) {

    $scope.Products = [];

    $scope.GetProducts = function() {
        ProductService.GetProducts().then
        (
            function(response) {
                $scope.Products = response;
            },
            function(error) {
                alert ('error worng');
            }
        );
    };

    $scope.GetProducts();


    $scope.$watch('ProductService.Products', function(newVal) {
        alert ('hitting watch');    // Not Reaching Here
        $scope.Products = NewVal;
        alert ($scope.Products);
    });
});
```

I am calling UpdateInfo in ProductService from some other service. Though its reaching to alert ('information updated'); in UpdateInfo. but not reaching to alert ('hitting watch'); in controller.

Can some one help me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of watching ProductsService.Products and then maintaining a seperate copy of that in Scope, why not use the same value itself.

Assign a reference to the service in your scope.

```
$scope.ProductService = ProductService;
```

In this way, you're ProductService is now exposed to the view. Now in your HTML page you can directly access ProductServices.Products and as soon as the value inside the service changes, they are automatically reflected in the View.

No dirty $Watch, no separate copies.

Edit : Going by @JB's answer, you must add an attribute named Products to the Service.

Something like this

```
    return {

            Products : [], 

            GetProducts: function () {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                $http(req).then(function(response) {
                    ProductService.Products = response.data;
                    defer.resolve(ProductService.Products);
                }, function(error) {
                    defer.reject("Some error");
                });
                return defer.promise;
            },

            ........
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I really appreciate the suggestion of Assign a reference to the service in your scope.

$scope.ProductService = ProductService;    But in this case how and where  to call the service function "GetProducts" to fetch the data from database.

Comment: You can call it anywhere. As long as your service variable is getting modified, you'll have the changes reflected in the view. Everything will remain the same, Except that there won't be any copies of Products inside your scope, you'll access them directly using Service reference.

Comment: I am using routeProvider in my code. The problem is  When i move to product template, ProductController come in picture. $scope.GetProducts(); will be called there and products will be filled from DB. now some service made the changes that will be reflected. Now when i move to some other template and then again to product template then  again $scope.GetProducts(); will be called. And my last updated products will go away..

Comment: You can move your product retrieval logc inside the app.run method, which will be called only once throughout your application lifetime. Have a look over the config and run part here : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Answer (score 2):

Your watch is for the expression 'ProductService.Products', and is evaluated on the scope of the controller. But this expression is and always will be evaluated as `undefined`, since the controller scope doesn't have a `ProductService` attribute.

Note that if you did

```
$scope.ProductService = ProductService
```

it wouldn't change much. Indeed, the expression would still be undefined, since `ProductService` doesn't have any attribute called `Products`. The only attributes is has are `GetProducts` and `UpdateInfo`, of type function.